# SQL Server - Try-Catch / xact_abort off and xact_state

Tags: sql-server, try-catch, xact-abort

We have a data import system where we are processing CSV files, each file contains a set of records that have to be validated and processed individually.  If they fail for some reason, they're marked with the error and we then go on to the next record.  They can fail for either logical or database errors such as dup key or foreign key errors.

The stored procedure that processes the data is either called from a client application, or from an agent job. The difference is that the app will create a transaction whereas the job will not before calling the proc.

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET XACT_ABORT OFF;

DECLARE @trancount_in       INT,
        @xstate             INT,
        @Row                INT,
        @MaxRows            INT

SET @trancount_in = @@trancount

-- CODE: import data into temp table
select @Row = 1,
       @MaxRows = @@Rowcount

IF @transcount_in = 0 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

while @Row <= @MaxRows

    -- CODE: Get data record from table  

    begin try

        save transaction myproc

        -- CODE: validate and process record

    end try

    begin catch

        SELECT @xstate = XACT_STATE()

        IF @xstate = -1 BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
            Raiserror('error',16,1)
        END
        IF @xstate = 1 and @@Trancount = 0 BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
            Raiserror('error',16,1)
        END
        IF @xstate = 1 and @@Trancount > 0
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION myproc

        -- CODE: update import record with error here

    end catch

    set @Row = @Row + 1
End

IF @transcount_in = 0 
    COMMIT
```

---

So fairly simple so far, but looking at lots of documentation, it says that you should check the xact_state for -1 in the catch block, but I don't want the transaction to fail at this point. I just want to go on to the next row in the import. So if xact_abort is off, would we ever get the xact_state of -1 in the catch block?

I know that the catch doesn't actually catch all errors, but I have found out that if you create a parent proc with a try catch block then it will catch more errors than the block in the actual proc. So I will be moving the loop logic to a parent proc and then just do the processing in the current one.

Is there anything else I should be doing to mitigate any errors that might occur?

Hope this isn't too confusing.
Cheers
Adrian

Comment: Nested transactions are a myth. If you `ROLLBACK` in the `CATCH` you roll back everything. You can't encapsulate the whole thing in a transaction, and then put each iteration in it's own one as well. You either need to put the whole lot in a transaction, *or* each iteration in it's own one.

Comment: Not a nested transaction, the proc only creates a trans if one doesn't already exist from the caller.  inside the loop, it's using s savepoint, not a transaction. and only on error is it rolling back the savepoint.    The transaction rollback in the catch is what I'm asking about really, I don't want it to do that unless absolutely necessary...  but so many articles say you have to do it if the xact_state is -1, but I'm not sure in my scenario that it will ever be -1 due to xact_abort being off.

Comment: You have `ROLLBACK`s in your `WHILE`, while your `BEGIN TRANSACTION` is outside of the `WHILE`, that means either nested transactions or you are going to be declaring more `ROLLBACK` clause that `BEGIN TRANSACTION` clauses. Both are flaws.

Comment: ignore the rollbacks in the code then..   at that point I'd probably be doing a raiserror to exit the proc due to something catastrophic.   I'm more interested in what would cause a non-recoverable catastrophic error and what I can do to trap it or ignore it.

Comment: updated the code to show a raiserror when a rollback was needed

Comment: [Obligatory article by Erland](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#BatchTranAbort) you want section 5.2. Basically, a deadlock, MAXRECURSION, conversion and arithmetic errors, out of space, compilation problems, connection problems, stack dumps: all cause batch abortion with rollback. It's not worth the headache to work out what will and won't work: just use `XACT_ABORT ON` and do things properly. So validate all rows to import, do the import and return invalid rows separately. Use a temp table if you have to. One thing I will guarantee: it will be much faster than what you have